# ReactJS - Trigger update of child component from another child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Given I have a parent component hosting two child components. I managed to create a ContextProvider sharing data between those two components. But I was unable to cause an refresh on Component2, triggered by an action on Component 1.

My scenario is one ore more child components refreshing data after a refresh button (think toolbar) in Component1 is clicked. I don´t want to lift the data from Component1 to the parent, as its only used by Component2. Can i define something like an event on the context shared by the components which can be raised by Component1 and consumed by Component2 or is there a different approach I should take?

Comment: Maybe try to pass parent's setState as child props and on refresh just call this refresh props.setState('updated');

Comment: Tried that one, but the second call to setState does not change the state, hence causes no update and always sending a different value does not feel quite right